# How to style ReportViewer tool bar

Tags: c#, wpf, reportviewer

I have a WPF application in which ive embedded an SSRS ReportViewer win form control. This works out fairly well for reporting purposes but the layout style of the ReportViewer clashes badly with the rest of the application. I've figured out how to change the background, and how to hide certain options from the toolbar, but I would like to style up the toolbar so that it matches the rest of the application better. The answer I found on MSDN points to the backColor property but that only changes the background of the reports rendering area, not the color of the toolbar. Heres a picture:

[image: Tool Bar Colors]

You can see that the BackColor which I set to black, changes the view area outside of the actual report to black, but not the tool bar. How can I modify the way that tool bar looks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273267.aspx) the Report Viewer is *actually* a WinForms controls being hosted by WPF.

Unfortunately, this means that the toolbar **cannot** be styled. The report itself can be styled via the RDLC file (as you seem to have found).